# Docker desktop WIN10 зависает

Tags: docker

Самого начала не заладилась работа с docker. Я попытался переустановить его с WSL2 (Первая итерация на HyperV была). Висит все, установка, деинсталлятор.
Висит на старте приложение Docker desktop - пишет

> Docker Desktop Starting

Консольная утилита на попытку создания volume  выдает

> docker volume create TestVolume

> error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/volumes/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified

После довольно длительной попытки стартануть вылезает окно с сообщением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое впечатление, что ему не хватает прокси(в Интернет ходим через прокси) и эта дрянь висит на сетевых таймаутах. Но я не очень понял как настроить прокси.

В файле

> \AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json

мне это не удается сделать оно при старте клиента перетирается.

WIN10 19042.1288, WSL2 установлен по инструкции.
В процессах висит

- Docker desktop
- com.docker.service
- com.docker.extensions.exe
- com.docker.backend.exe
- com.docker.dev-envs.exe

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

Справляется также с зависшими контейнерами (которые висят на stop бесконечно)